"Failed to fetch" on github actions since today
I have a yml workflow running in ubuntu for deploying documentation for a julia package, and it used to work until today.
Now I get the following error:
in expression starting at stdin:E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-xorg-dev_21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7%7e22.04.11_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 20.106.104.242 80]

Re-running the previous commit's workflow, which was previously passing without any issues, now leads to the same error.
Thus I believe it has nothing to do with my package, but it's probably about the line :
run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y xorg-dev mesa-utils xvfb libgl1 freeglut3-dev libxrandr-dev libxinerama-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev libxext-dev

Did any updates take place during the last few days which could cause this?
I'm looking for ways to fix this but I'm completely clueless, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

You didn't specifically provide Ubuntu product/release details; but your details match a non-updated jammy system trying to get an outdated package; ie. xserver-xorg-dev | 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.12 | jammy-security appears to be what you should be looking for but are instead trying to download an older version (time lapse between commands or other user-controlled issue inc. bad luck & not considering time..).. Check your sources/mirror etc.

Thank you very much for the hint, guiverc. Would it be possible to give an example of how my command should look like instead? Also, do we know why was it working fine so far, but now it doesn't? (as you can tell, my knowledge is minimal, and I'm trying to learn a bit more)

My comment was based on what you posted, where your message shows an attempt to download package 21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.11, so I did a CLI enquiry as to what packages are correct/up-to-date for each release and jammy or 22.04 shows 21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.12  ... indicating I'd check your sources for what mirror you're using (is it up to date) AND when you last run sudo apt update to update software lists; as your machine is looking for an OLDER file than what it should be... ie. I explored only what you provided.

Would it be possible to edit the mirror in the case of the virtual machine used by github actions? Or, is there a way to modify my commands so that it looks for the correct version instead? Sorry if these questions sound silly, I'm just really new to these sort of workflows.

Your machine software lists are outdated, and thus the fix is to run sudo apt update and actually notice the output/command to ensure it completes successfully without warnings/errors etc.  You mention running the command, but give no clues as to when OR if you actually confirmed there were no problems/warnings/errors (we can't see the output, being limited to details you provide).
